# Whats the best approach to analyse a data source (csv) to then extract the deltas (changes) only to a destination source?

Tags: sql, powershell, csv, ssis, compare

For my example, I'm looking to compare a source file with some changes made to the attributes in a table - lets say in the form of another source file.

What i want to achieve is

---

[Sourcefile.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b50h.png)

---

[Newfile.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcA5H.png)

Deltafile.csv

(this will export only the changes deltas (rows) between the two files)

What i would like to achieve is that the row with the changes is exported as the delta, not just the column attribute.

All other rows that match do not need to be updated.

```
100,Renie,Stav,Renie.Stav@yopmail.com,Renie.Stav@gmail.com,CHANGE
101,Neila,Germann,CHANGE,Neila.Germann@gmail.com,developer
```

---

I've looked at Powershell, FC and SSIS incremental loading to see if this will work for my needs but a need some guidance in the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

**Current Method **

Looking indepth at the powershell i tried in https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/cea8ax/compare_2_csv_files_and_export_the_rows_that_do/

Which is

```
# Compare work
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\G23\Documents\Hackingfolder\source.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\G23\Documents\Hackingfolder\new.csv
$head = (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\G23\Documents\Hackingfolder\source.csv | Select-Object -First 1) -split ","
Compare-Object $csv1 $csv2 -Property $head -PassThru| Export-Csv C:\Users\G23\Documents\Hackingfolder\TheDiff.csv -NoTypeInformation
# Remove side indicator if you dont care to know where the diff came from
Compare-Object $csv1 $csv2 -Property $head | Select-Object -Property $head
```

Ignoring the side indicators i would get the rows that would not match, both of them. its not smart enough to know which one is the updated one. e.g I want the exported delta changes rows only.

[PowerShell output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj1Dd.png)

instead of the desired below changes only in csv

```
100,Renie,Stav,Renie.Stav@yopmail.com,Renie.Stav@gmail.com,CHANGE
101,Neila,Germann,CHANGE,Neila.Germann@gmail.com,developer
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Add-Member to add additional properties to each row of the CSV after importing to a table.  See my answer at following how to use Add-Member : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74631388/in-powershell-how-do-i-loop-through-csv-file-and-create-a-summary-hashtable-base/74631985#74631985

Comment: SSIS answer... you can load both sources through flat file source and use a merge join using full outer and use ALL columns as your join key. Where ever your source is null means that there was a change. So conditionally split out rows where source.ID is null and those are your changes. Merge join requires running both sides through a sort.

Comment: Please use fabricated names and email addresses in sample data if they’re real.

Comment: @KeithL - thanks for that, I have it working to my requirements!

Comment: @JHH data was generated via https://extendsclass.com/csv-generator.html